# Editor placeholder in source file error in handler

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried a lot of things (putting   _ :UIAlertAction inside openPage func and inside handler trying different closure etc.) but when there is no Editor placeholder  error i get another error.

What is "Edtor placeholder  in source file" possible errors and solutions

```
@objc func resenje(){
    let ac = UIAlertController (title: "Prikaz dodavanja drugog tab-a", message: "Zbog novije verzije xCode-a", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "https://www.reddit.com",
                               style: .default,
                               handler:{ [weak self] action in self?.openPage() })) 
                                       //Editor placeholder in source file !
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
func openPage(){
    let url = URL(string: title!)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: Seems like there's a special/invisible character on that line that you accidentally pressed from keyboard? Can you try deleting that line / writing it again? (DO NOT cut/paste).

Comment: (Or copy/paste into an editor like BBEdit that shows special charcters.)

Answer (score 0):

When you use auto-complete to add template code into your source files, the templates often include placeholders, or strings marked with markup characters, that you are supposed to replace with actual values for your use-case. Function parameters are the most common example of this.

Example: When I type in `UIImage(named:`, Xcode fills it in with the full function template, plus a placeholder for the value. Viewed outside of Xcode, what I get is:

`UIImage(named: <#T##String#>)!`

(Note the `<#T##String#>` bit, which stands for "variable of type `String`".)

I don't see any placeholders in the code you posted however.

Comment: I will post a whole code because this does not seems like a problem to simulator